# Recovering samples from a density estimation with an additional prior on the samples. Used for Gibbs sampling

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, curve-fitting, gibbs

**Abstract Idea**:

- Given a noisy measured density ($d_j$ at position $p_j$) and a density model, sample from the model parameters under the following stochastic model:

**Stochastic Model**:

1. Prior for model parameters $\theta$: $p(\theta)$
2. $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \dots , x_L \in \mathbb{R}$, $L \ggg 1 $, i.i.d samples from $p(x_i|\theta)$.
3. Sample density estimates $\{d_j\}_{j=1}^N$ at position $\{p_j\}_{j=1}^N$ from $\mathcal{N}(d_j | \frac{1}{L}\sum_{i=1}^L k(x_i-p_j), \sigma_0^2) = p(d_j|\{x_i\}_{i=1}^L)$, where $k$ is some kernel (such as a gaussian).
4. Thus the joint probability density is:
   $$
   p(\{d_j\}_{j=1}^N,\{x_i\}_{i=1}^L,\theta) =  \left(\prod_{j=1}^N p(d_j|\{x_i\}_{i=1}^L)\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^L p(x_i|\theta)\right) p(\theta)
   $$

**Solution Sketch:**

- Task: Sample $\theta \, \mid \, \{d_j\}_{j=1}^N$ using a MCMC algorithm (Gibbs sampler), for this we need to sample from the conditional distributions:
- Sampling $\theta^{t+1}$ from $p(\theta^{t+1} | \{x^t_i\}_{i=1}^L)$ is in principle extremely hard, but well studied and large, fast libraries (implemented in C) are available for exactly this problem.
- **I'm stuck here:** Sampling from $p(\{x^{t+1}_i\}_{i=1}^L | \{d^t_j\}_{j=1}^N, \theta^t)$, I feel like this problem should be well studied in the literature, as essentially what I want to recover are the most likely samples under some observed density and some prior information on the underlying density. However, I can't seem to find this in the literature. Any pointers to papers/keywords that deal with this problem would be super helpful! My current ideas are mostly restricted to assume $L \ggg 1$ such that $p(\{x^{t+1}_i\}_{i=1}^L | \{d^t_j\}_{j=1}^N, \theta^t)$ can be approximated by an factorized distribution $\prod_i q(x^{t+1}_i)$, but I'm kinda stuck here.

Comment: It's not so clear what you are trying to achieve here. Since you start by sampling $\theta$ you know exactly with which values of  $\theta$ the samples $x_i$ were generated. What is the point of using this data to estimate back $\theta$ ?

Comment: I don't know $\theta$, I'm trying to sample the random variable $\theta$ conditioned on $\{d_j\}_{j=1}^N$. For that I use an gibbs sampler which requires me to sample from x and $\theta$ iteratively using the appropriate conditional distribution.  The problem is that I struggle to sample from one of the conditional distributions. I also added a $t$ index to signify the gibbs sample for iteration $t$.

Comment: Why are you resampling the $x_i$?  You have the data ($d_j, p_j$) and the model $p(p_j, d_j | \theta)$, and that's all you need for the likelihood function $\mathcal{L}(\theta ; p, d)$, which, combined with the prior, gives you something proportional to the posterior.  You can then sample the $\theta$ using MCMC from there.

Comment: @jbowman This approach is indeed possible, however sampling from the posterior you proposed is *difficult* as $\theta$ is actually representative of roughly 120 parameters. In the literature Reversible-jump MCMC and particle filters are then used to sample from that posterior. However, they suffer from performance issues (if done in R), unphysical choice of priors etc. Most of these problem could be avoided if $\theta$ is sampled from $p(\theta | \{x_i\}_{i=1}^{L})$ (using R libs for Inference for mixtures models). But this comes at the cost of having to sample $x_i$

Comment: "I feel like this problem should be well studied in the literature": this is a very exotic problem, where the data is turned into a kernel density estimate, itself observed with noise. Consider the limiting case $\sigma_0=0$: I would not know how to handle it.

Comment: It seems to me that the main difficulty here is that the likelihood $p(d|\theta)$ is intractable (unless you can calculate $\int dx p(d|x) p(x|\theta)$, in which case you can follow @jbowman's suggestion). If this is the case you should look at [Likelihood-free MCMC methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2058)